combining uncertainties
i have this dataset:



$y_{observed}$
$\sigma_{stat}^+$
$\sigma_{stat}^-$
$\sigma_{sys}^+$
$\sigma_{sys}^-$




0.193
0.002
-0.002
0.0316
-0.0218


0.1504
0.0014
-0.0014
0.0158
-0.0121


0.13507
0.00079
-0.00079
0.01092
-0.00787


0.11647
0.00072
-0.00072
0.00846
-0.00603


$\vdots$
$\vdots$
$\vdots$
$\vdots$
$\vdots$



$stat$ stands for statistical and $sys$ stands for systematic.
My understanding is that I can sum in quadrature $\sigma_{stat}$ and $\sigma_{sys}$ since they are uncorrelated
$$
\sigma_{total} = \sqrt{ (\sigma_{stat})^2+(\sigma_{sys})^2}
$$
therefore i would have:
$$
\sigma_{total}^+ = \sqrt{ (\sigma_{stat}^+)^2+(\sigma_{sys}^+)^2}
$$
$$
\sigma_{total}^- = \sqrt{ (\sigma_{stat}^-)^2+(\sigma_{sys}^-)^2}
$$
Can I combine $\sigma_{total}^+$ and $\sigma_{total}^-$ in some way? I think they are  correlated, right? How should I handle the combination of $\sigma_{total}^+$ and $\sigma_{total}^-$?

I think this question might be better suited to Cross Validated.

@ZoeAllen Oh, alright! i will post there, thanks!
